# RabbitMQ: How to get json data in message rates chart of queue

Tags: rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ Management Web Interface, looking at Queues tab, I can see message rate chart, and If I want to get json data that was stored for plotting in chart, please give me some suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current number of messages in the queue via the following URL:

`http://<host>:<port>/api/queues/<vhost>/<queue>`

That will return *JSON*, and you would want to look at the *messages* attribute.

Comment: thanks, actually I want to get a modify json that management plugin use for plotting a chart